# HTML different from server on IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I create an asp.net page.

- Test local on IE, working.
- Test local on Firefox, working.

I put on my server

- Test local on Firefox, working.
- Test local on Chrome, working.
- Test local on IE, design not working. Things wrong position.

Use Save-As of firefox on server page.

- Test on firefox, html saved page working.
- Test on IE, html saved page not working. Things wrong position.

Use Save-As of IE on server page

- Test on firefox, html saved page working.
- Test on IE, html saved page not working. Things wrong position.

Use Save-As of IE on local page

- Test on firefox, html saved page working.
- Test on IE, html saved page not working. Things wrong position.

Why it's working local on IE?

What should I check on my page (maybe encoding, header, ...)?

Comment: IE defaults to compatibility mode for remote sites and quirks mode for localhost.  It's the stupidest thing they (the developers of IE) did in a very long line of stupid things.

Comment: I found it. I had a "padding: 0;". I need to create another css only for IE with "margin:0px;"

Comment: Tank you Paul. You remember me that IE is a freak.